# Split assets into bundles in Production with Webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, production

I see on almost every production website made in React (or in almost every other framework), that there are splitted css and js bundles inserted into HTML website.

I am using Webpack 4 with this configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/client/index.js",
    output: {
        path: outputPath,
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputPath]),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

But when I build my frontend and serve it by Express, my CSS styles are inlined by `<style></style>` and also included in main.js file.
How to split CSS,JS and other assets from each other (bundle.css, bundle.js, img/image1.png, etc) instead of inlining CSS and converting images into base64 format?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new file for css, remove `style-loader` and add https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

To do the same with files, remove `url-loader` and replace it with `file-loader`